# Stop Visual Studio 2015 using project instead of package in solution

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget, dnx

It seems VS2015 will default to using the project if it finds one rather than the nuget package for dependencies. Is there a way to tell it not to? Any project that is located at the same level as the dependant project gets loaded by visual studio into the solution, I would rather it use the package unless I tell it otherwise.

I have tried an empty project list in the global.json file. I have even removed the global.json file. Still it finds the projects.

Directory structure looks something like the following:

Root

--global.json

--src

----Core

----Language

----Runtime

Runtime depends on Language and Core. Core and Language are nuget packages and available through my private feed.

I have read the reasons why this is useful, for debugging packages etc. and I agree it can be useful but I would prefer if I can control it when I need to.

Thanks,

Nick

Answer (score 0):

Update:

Found a solution in the ASP.NET beta 8 release notes:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2015/10/15/announcing-availability-of-asp-net-5-beta8.aspx

**Explicitly target dependencies at packages or projects**

You can now explicitly specify the target type for a dependency in project.json to ensure that the dependency only comes from a package or a project:

```
"dependencies": {
    "ClassLibrary1": { "version": "1.0.0-*", "target": "project" },
    "ClassLibrary2": { "version": "1.0.0-*", "target": "package" }
}
```